# how to write an fql query to list friends in a particular location

Tags: android, facebook-fql

I can't find anywhere an fql query to list my facebook friends according to a location I that I specify.I am trying to implement this fql query in android.Someone please help me.

Comment: Try this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/run-fql-queries/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FQL you are looking for will be

```
select name, current_location
from user 
where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) 
  and current_location.country = "India" 
  and current_location.state ="Delhi"
```

The above FQL filters out the friends of the user and returns list of user's friends with `current_location` as Delhi, India. You can further filter the list based on other attributes of `current_location` like `city`, `zip`, `latitude`, `longitude` and others.

You would require the additional `friends_location` permission to access the location from the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) FQL table.

Comment: String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND hometown_location.country='"+location+"'";

This is my android side fql query but still i am not able to get the result

Comment: When i write this fql query i get the result but the search includes myself too and when i remove the part " uid = me() OR" i dont get any result

Comment: As per your comments, I think you are not having the permission for `friends_hometown`.